# Why is this IMPORTRANGE formula not working?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I keep getting an error while using the IMPORTRANGE formula:

```
=importrange(“1uUbz2HAzgwBwY3zMXqcLJM_Z8qVQZHNP0wzRaNHceTc”, “Sheet1!A:B”)
```

I changed the name of my sheets several times to make sure everything matches but see a:

> Formula parse error

and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. The original sheet has several tabs as well.

Can you see where the error is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me:

`=importrange(“1uUbz2HAzgwBwY3zMXqcLJM_Z8qVQZHNP0wzRaNHceTc”; “Sheet1!A:B”)`

Maybe try it with a semicolon

Comment: Semicolon worked! To bad Google themself does not say anything about this solution

Comment: This is a regional thing. Some regions use commas and some use semicolons in formulas.

Answer (score 3):

Add the link format
eg
`=importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uUbz2HAzgwBwY3zMXqcLJM_Z8qVQZHNP0wzRaNHceTc","Sheet1!A:B")` this should fix it

Comment: The link format is not required but can be used if desired.

Answer (score 2):

One other issue that can prevent import range from working is leading or trailing space in your sheet name.  Make you check the sheet tab and clean out any leading or trailing spaces or your formula won't work.  :-)

I burned an hour reading this thread and recreating my formula over and over again before I finally found the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have it as `Sheet1!A:B`, but you are missing the single quotes to identify the sheet name.

It should be `'Sheet1'!A:B` instead.
The full formula is below:

```
=importrange(“1uUbz2HAzgwBwY3zMXqcLJM_Z8qVQZHNP0wzRaNHceTc”, “'Sheet1'!A:B”)
```

Comment: Just a note: quotes are only required if the sheet name has a space in it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the sheet you're trying to import from is saved as a google sheet. I was trying to import an .xls file into a google sheet, and it wouldn't work. I re-saved the sheet as a google sheet and it fixed the problem immediately.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

This formula does not work

`=importrange(“1uUbz2HAzgwBwY3zMXqLJM_Z8qVQZHNP0aNHceTc”,“Sheet1!A:B”)`

### Reason why

You use curly double quotes `“ ”` instead of straight double quotes `" "`

### SOLUTION

**Change the quotes** from curly to straight
`=importrange("1uUbz2HAzgwBwY3zMXqLJM_Z8qVQZHNP0aNHceTc","Sheet1!A:B")`

**Be careful**
If you have different locale you must also change `,` to `;`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (I'm from France).
I solved it by replacing "," with ";" (between URL and cell location).
Probably some language issues too.
Sorry for digging old post but I hope this could help too.